# Partial function parameters type

Tags: typescript, types, parameters, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a type for a function "factory", issue is, I do not know the number of arguments in the callback beforehand. Consider the following factory builder

```
type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

function apply<F extends Fn>(fn: F, ...aplyArgs: Parameters<F>) {
   return (...args: Parameters<F>) => fn(...(aplyArgs || []), ...(args || []))
}
```

Now this is a fairly common pattern, consider this built factory.

```
function add(a: number, b: number) {
   return a + b
}

// this throws error, Parameters expects 2 args, got 1
const plus2 = apply(add, 2)

// this also throws error for the same reason
plus2(2) // 4
```

Now the issue is clear to me, the `Parameters` utility type expects you to use all parameters and not just some of the parameters. I essentially need to create two types `ApplyArgs` which will be the initial parameters used and `RestArgs` which will be the remaining parameters.

I tried manually and somewhat clunkily to define a possible amount of args, which does actually provide a correct type for the params:

```
type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

export type P<F extends Fn, Id extends number> = Parameters<F>[Id]

type GetParamUntil<F extends Fn, Id extends number> = Id extends 3
  ? [P<F, 0>, P<F, 1>, P<F, 2>, P<F, 3>]
  : Id extends 2
    ? [P<F, 0>, P<F, 1>, P<F, 2>]
    : Id extends 1
      ? [P<F, 0>, P<F, 1>]
      : Id extends 0
        ? [P<F, 0>]
        : never

type ApplyArgs<F extends Fn> = |
 GetParamUntil<F, 0> |
 GetParamUntil<F, 1> |
 GetParamUntil<F, 2> |
 GetParamUntil<F, 3>

type GetParamsFrom<F extends Fn, Params extends ApplyArgs<F>> = Params extends GetParamUntil<F, 0>
  ? [P<F, 1>, P<F, 2>, P<F, 3>]
  : Params extends GetParamUntil<F, 1>
    ? [P<F, 2>, P<F, 3>]
    : [P<F, 3>]


function apply<F extends Fn, Params extends ApplyArgs<F>>(fn: F, ...aplyArgs: Params) {
   return (...args: GetParamsFrom<F, Params>) => fn(...(aplyArgs || []), ...(args || []))
}
```

Which actually does somewhat work

```
function add(a: number, b: number) {
   return a + b
}

// this now works
const plus2 = apply(add, 2)

// this somewhat works, but throws ts error
plus2(2) // 4
```

The issue stems from the fact, that the function has correct types for params, but the paramters length does not fit

Even though the rest params are technically `undefined` as they rightfully should be, since we supplied ts with a tuple of defined length, it expects said length for params.

[image]

In general this is a rather clunky solution and is not scalable with the technically infinite amount of params. Biggest issue stems from the fact, that I cannot recursively pass an index to infer an array index from certain point, i.e. `type Until<Id> = [infer Params[0:Id]`. Without it I'm not sure if this is even possible

You can find the [shared ts playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdlAvFAFAOgwQwE4HMDOAXFJnCANoC6AlEgHwlkBQTEAHmAPbbBSiRQACgB4YUdsAhwAJvlhwANFACS08W0ky5cAK4BbAEYRsDZIJyY9ESdnyi65VZRb9oAcWvnslgKpxgAJYANqLqmrLySqphUhG6hsamKmoSsXIAzExQUAD8UOQiMEoADHRKhUoAjGVCokoATDUVUOl0ztnE0alaUPVZ2bn5zaXldVDVo0W9bf0dyTE9lbMDeQVjI7VT1e0Dc10aaVDFy7urwzO7u8RwEABuxi7g0ACCYGBBIM94dmLdEfBJDzALy+fzBdYMAA+UCBIL0fkCIS2UJhngs8LBSIaKNh6IR4KmrUeAlx3j0+Bg2E4elCfzk8HK6LkdKgr3en2+9iScOZBx6pNBiIh-TOYwmm2xkyUrR2xB5CwiAoxQuRy1FU0aUpaFwGxDWhJmLAAZjo4ABjQKcBCYN4fWl8-6KIRMhVyNkfL4ELkoI1wYhTDBoG0e75ypm0ADes2w1h02AQ6CwodRwKZlOpYx5dFoiAYvsTaBQwY5BCgkOhVGoSkDRe+ZYrNGoTAAvsbTRaAlaSNJpEXrvojNglAZ+wlsJHo7H4yQoABqKAGFssM1W-C8d46fD1JAkW0gIs9hpNpgbrcoeq0AD0l6gABYgA) :)

Comment: I like this fun solution here that uses tuple manipulation: https://tsplay.dev/m335ym

Comment: putting my solution into the mix: https://tsplay.dev/wOxJRN. Its similar to @caTS solution, but I used the `ApplyArgs` from your question and modified it to be a mapped type.

Comment: @caTS @TobiasS feels almost silly with how elegant the solution is compared to mine. My biggest hurdle was, I for some reason blanked out on the fact not only I can infer the rest params for end (`[infer P, ...infer Rest]`) but also the other way around for the ending element. `[...infer Rest, infer P]`. Thanks a lot guys, if either of you feel like posting the answer so I can accept the answer, feel free to, otherwise guess I'll just recap it like a week later so it can get marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

First, reworking your `ApplyArgs` type (admittedly, the name of this type could use some work):

```
type UpTo<A> = A extends readonly [...infer Rest, any] ? A | UpTo<Rest> : A;

type T = UpTo<[1, 2, 3]> // [1, 2, 3] | [1, 2] | [1] | []
```

Then another type to skip the given parameters:

```
type Skip<S extends any[], T> = T extends [...S, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : never;
```

We get a pretty intuitive and readable function signature:

```
function apply<F extends (...args: any[]) => any, Params extends UpTo<Parameters<F>>>(fn: F, ...applied: Params) {
   return (...args: Skip<Params, Parameters<F>>) => fn(...(applied || []), ...(args || [])) as ReturnType<F>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAqB7APAQQHxQLxVVCAHsBAHYAmAzlAE4QCGZiJANiFANoB03AliQGYRqUAEoQKwADRQ6JEAF0oAflxQAPrAQoxEzAC5cAbgBQx0JCjxsmpMnYBGaQCZpAZnnpT56AGUA1jxgyD74RKSUMnLs8tLwmDhWhMTkVFzcPtLcnHyCwjrAiir5UAYkEABuQibG-ACuJADGwDxMMmBgrMgAYqHJEQAUWXTUAOYUBrIg0QCU2JiT0gAKw3QAtlRJ4VRwtsvUaxDE1BTd6Gf9-CQGXZncdO3MPBBkBntrFLMA3sZQv7TAtWoJCggzuo3GUH8gWQb3WSxWq0OQhOXTOsywmEuoM4-XuHSeZHUGhmtxxwzGRI48mmszoVDEAKB8HAEFOJgAvqY6o1mq0GGRcaVaqsAEZCaQioWioRfH5-Q6A4F0KAAaigIuMnOMDSYEigHVqFCc1jxrFxZDIzmmpgNRv6TmmhiAA)